# How should I return an Image from a controller action c# asp.net-mvc-2?

Tags: c#, javascript, image, asp.net-mvc-2, actionmethod

I am building images from a `byte[]` like below.

```
public FileContentResult GetEmployeeImage(int empId)
{
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
   Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
   return returnImage;//How should i return this image to be consumed by javascript.
}
```

I want to return this image to the browser via a controller action method, so as it can be consumed by my javascript code and displayed in the browser. How should I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to create an image object; you just want to return the raw data.
The browser will read the raw data into an image.

```
return File(byteArray, "image/png");
```

Obviously, you need to pass the correct content type, depending on what image format is in the byte array.

Comment: @Slaks: Thanks for your response. So how can i can consume this in javascript?

Comment: Provide JavaScript the path to your action which returns the image and handle the result as you would any other image request.

Comment: Do you mean: return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/png");

Comment: @Slaks: the `return Content(byteArray, "image/png");` expected a string as first parameter. So I took Lee Gunn's advice from above and used `return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/png")` is this correct? @Nathan Taylor: Forgive me for being a bit dumb here, but can you provide a short example of what you mean?thanks

Comment: @Nathan Taylor: Actually I have figured it out. Stupid me. I get what you mean now thanks.

Comment: @Lee, @Shane: My mistake; I meant `File`.  Fixed.